# initial blob is playing, from second blob is not playing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webrtc, fetch-api

```
componentDidMount() {
        navigator.mediaDevices
            .getUserMedia({ video: true})
            .then(stream => { this.handleSuccess(this.videoTag.current.srcObject = stream) })
            .catch(console.log);

    }


handleSuccess(stream) {
        console.log('st',stream)
        media_recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            media_recorder.start(10000);
            media_recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', function (e) {
                console.log('e.data', e.data)
                var reader = new FileReader();
                var base64data
                reader.readAsDataURL(e.data);
                reader.onload = function () {
                    base64data = reader.result;
                    const base64EncodedData = base64data.split(',')[1];
                    const body = JSON.stringify({
                        data: base64EncodedData
                    });
                    fetch('http://localhost:3090/api/recording', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                            'Accept': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body
                    }).then(res => {
                        return res.json()
                    }).then(json => console.log(json));                    
                }
            });
}
```

from the webcam i am continuously generating blob at regular intervals then i am encoding to base64 and decoding at server level which helps me to generate mp4 files in local storage but the issue was when i started the playing those generated files only initial file is playing, from second file onward it is not playing  can any one help to solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is how the `MediaRecorder` works. The chunks emitted by the `dataavailable` events are not necessarily self contained. It's only guaranteed that they make sense when combined again.

I think in your case the initial part is playing since it looks like a complete file to the decoder. All consecutive parts probably miss any header (since they are meant to get appended to the first part) and therefore don't get recognized by the decoder.

Maybe you have the chance to decode the full recording in chunks again instead of decoding the individual parts.

Comment: the requirement is to do with individual chunk if it is full chunk or single it is working fine but i want for individual chunk and how can i get header of very first blob if i attach the header to second blob hope it will work fine

Comment: It depends a bit on the file format used by the `MediaRecorder` but most of the time it's possible to augment the chunks with a header to turn it into a complete file.